# JSON array returns undefined unless presented as a var in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I know that there are many questions like this one but none match the problem I am having.

I am trying to parse a JSON array passed from my php, I can access the JSON array but only at the top level. After that I get an undefined error.

The survey_data JSON

```
{test: "{"title":"test","data":{"questions":{"test":{"name":"test","type":"text","options":",,"}}}}", The New Survey: "{"title":"The New Survey","data":{"questions":{"te…":{"name":"test","type":"text","options":",,"}}}}"}
```

Here is my JS code

```
var survey_data = <?php echo json_encode($survey_data); ?>;
    $(document).on( "click", ".view", function() {
       var survey_name = $(this).closest('tr').find(".quest-name-list").text();
       console.log(survey_data[survey_name]['title']);
    });
```

If I run `console.log(survey_data[survey_name]);` I get the JSON

```
{"title":"test","data":{"questions":{"test":{"name":"test","type":"text","options":",,"}}}}
```

But the above `console.log(survey_data[survey_name]['title']);` returns undefined

If I run the below code though it works

```
var json = {"title":"test","data":{"questions":{"test":{"name":"test","type":"text","options":",,"}}}};
console.log(survey_data[survey_name]['title']);
```

This will return the desired JSON field, I can not figure out why though.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Thanks to everyone who helped me walk through the problem, here is the problem and fix.

In my php code I had

```
$survey_data = [];
        foreach ($surveys as $survey) {
           $survey_fi = $survey['survey_fields'];           
           $survey_data[ $survey_f['title']] = imap_base64($survey_fi);
             }
```

But the field($survey_fi) that I was adding to the array was already JSON, so I needed to decode the JSON first and then add it the array that would be converted back to JSON in my JS code.

This is the solution

```
$survey_data = [];
        foreach ($surveys as $survey) {
           $survey_fi = $survey['survey_fields'];   
           $survey_f = json_decode(imap_base64($survey_fi), true);
           $survey_data[ $survey_f['title']] = $survey_f;
             }
```

Comment: Without seeing more context it's going to be very difficult for anybody to help. The code you posted would, on its own, work just fine.

Comment: What is the full content of `survey_data`?

Comment: @PatrickQ I have edited my answer to include the content of survey_data

Comment: @Top-Bot the json you added to the question doesn't look valid

Comment: Yeah, that's _not_ JSON

Comment: @Top-Bot Just for the sake of sanity, try this: `var survey_data; try { survey_data = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($survey_data); ?>'); } catch (err) { console.log(err); } console.log(survey_data); ` and see if javascript is able to produce valid JSON from what it's getting

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found the issue in my php. I will update the answer to show what went wrong.

Comment: You json_encoded pieces of the $survey_data variable separately, and then json_encoded the whole variable again, it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I think `survey_data[survey_name]` is JSON string and there won't be any `title` property for a string so parse it before trying to get the property.

```
console.log(JSON.parse(survey_data[survey_name])['title']);
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense

Comment: `survey_name` doesn't seem to contain json

Comment: And why do you think so, interesting?

Comment: @dfsq : confused b/w variable name

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca You were right, see my updated answer.